# How to determine that one array is a part of another one?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

For instance: I have array

```
var src = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var tag = new byte[] {3, 4};
```

Who know fast method to find index of tag's array?
I need something as following:

```
int FindIndexOfSeq(byte[] src, byte[] sequence);
```

a sequence can be in more than one times in src.

Solution: [How to find index of sublist in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list

Comment: This is not an easy problem to solve efficiently. The naïve, easy-to implement-search is `O(nm)` worst case. You can improve on that substantially (e.g. Boyer-Moore), but it's not easy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms

Comment: Only the index of the first occurrence?

Comment: Ani is totally right, the solution I provided is O(nm) for any type of sequence... but if the sequences are ordered and the items only occurs one time in each sequence my solution will result in O(n). What you need depend on your requirements, and if you have large data sets etc. An O(n) solution could be slower than O(nm) for small sets if the constant factor is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int FindIndexOfSeq<T>(byte[] src, byte[] tag)
{
    Int32 tagCount = tag.Count();            

    // If `tag` is not empty and `src` contains `tag`
    if (tagCount > 0 && src.Intersect(tag).Count() == tagCount)
    {
        // Find index of first element in `tag`
        Int32 tagStartIndex = Array.IndexOf(src, tag.First());

        // Get the matching slice of `tag` from `src`
        var newSrc = src.Skip(tagStartIndex).Take(tag.Count()).ToList();

        // Zip them together using their difference
        var sum = Enumerable.Zip(tag, newSrc, (i1, i2) => Convert.ToInt32(i2 - i1)).Sum();

        // If total of their differences is zero, both sequences match
        if (sum == 0)
        {
            // return starting index of `tag` in `src`
            return tagStartIndex;
        }
    }

    // return `Not Found`
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that get it wrong if src is { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 } and tag is { 3, 4 } ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to the get the index

```
for (int i = 0; i < (src.Length - tag.Length); i++ )
{
    if (tag.SequenceEqual(src.Skip(i).Take(tag.Length)))
        Console.WriteLine("It's at position " + i);
}
```

Unfortunately it's very slow.

If you just want to know if all of items in `tag` can be found in `src` (in any order) then

```
var src = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
var tag = new byte[] { 4, 3 };

if (src.Intersect(tag).Count() == tag.Length)
    Console.WriteLine("tag can be found in src!");
```

Comment: No, I need to know the index where the sequence begins.

Comment: Jonas, in yours sample you have the wrong order of bytes in tag's array.

Comment: I don't think this will work if `tag` contains duplicate elements. Or even if `src` does.

Comment: @Dmitriy... He has it like that to show you that he returns true if he founds all element disregarding the order.

Comment: @Jon I guess not but it depends on how Dmitriy wants to handle those cases.

Comment: computational complexity of this solution is enormous.

Comment: @Andrey I benchmarked it and you are correct, it's horribly slow.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can get is O(m), but that I slightly complex implementation. If you satisfy with a solution that has O(m*n) as worst case you can go with the solution below. If your sequences are ordered and the starting item in the `tag` array is only present one time in `src` this will also result in O(m).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var src = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var tag = new byte[] { 3, 4 };
        var index = FindIndexOfSeq(src, tag);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static int FindIndexOfSeq<T>(T[] src, T[] seq)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length - seq.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            bool foundSeq = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < seq.Length; j++)
            {
                foundSeq = foundSeq && src[i + j].Equals(seq[j]);
            }
            if (foundSeq)
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

I assumed the sequence have to be in that order and I have only compiled it in firefox, so not sure if it works :). Also, I made it generic so it handles any type of arrays not just bytes.

**UPDATE:** The updated code compiles and work... or my simple test worked.

Comment: You *can* improve on `O(nm)`, in fact it's possible to do it in `O(n)`.  Example: Boyer-Moore. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: You are right... I updated that part and included a simple program. Also, you're correct with the O(n), but that seems like a much more complicated algorithm? Is it faster on small sets? I think there is a small trade off there. If his sequence look like the one he provided that will result in O(n+m).

Comment: Yes, I agree implementing any of those is possibly overkill for most common uses. But I would still get rid of "The best you can get is O(m*n)"; it's a little misleading.

Comment: `foundSeq = true &&`? Isn't `true &&` a no-op?

Comment: I meant to write `foundSeq && ...`, but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Updated to fix if src ends with sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This task is equal to searching substring in string. For this you may use any KMP algorithm for better performance:
http://exclusiveminds.com/2009/12/09/kmp-string-searching-algorithm-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

[How to find index of sublist in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list)

Comment: That question does not have an accepted answer. Which one did you prefer?