# LINQ List Contains Another List (Contiguous)

Tags: linq, contains

I'm having trouble finding an efficient but simple way to check if a list contains another list (retaining order). It's analogous to the string.Contains(string) functionality.

Say I have four collections of ints:

```
 A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 B = [2, 3]
 C = [5, 6, 7]
 D = [3, 2, 4]
```

`A.Contains(B)` would be true, while `A.Contains(C)` and `A.Contains(D)` would be false.

I'd rather not use iterators if it can be helped, but I can't imagine an efficient way to do it; the following code is wildly inefficient.

```
 public static bool IsSequentiallyEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lhs, IEnumerable<T> rhs)
 {
      return lhs.Zip(rhs, (a, b) => a.Equals(b)).All(isEqual => isEqual == true);
 }

 public static bool StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle)
 {
      return haystack.Take(needle.Count()).IsSequentiallyEqual(needle);
 }

 public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle)
 {
      var result = list.SkipWhile((ele, index) => haystack.Skip(index).StartsWith(needle));
      return result.Count() >= needle.Count();
 }
```

Comment: How many items will you have? (That is to say, is efficiency crucial, or do you just want something that's not very inefficient?)

Comment: It won't be enough to REQUIRE efficiency, but it would be nice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list

Comment: Is there a way to cleanly implement any of those via LINQ?

Comment: By cleanly do you mean "without cluttering up source code with the required logic?"

Comment: Okay, I'll retract that. Is there a way to implement it with a series of chained LINQ statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle)
{
    var hayList = haystack.ToList();
    var needleList = needle.ToList();
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hayList.Count)
                     .Select(start => hayList.Skip(start).Take(needleList.Count))
                     .Any( subsequence => subsequence.SequenceEqual(needleList));
}
```

Comment: Still O(N^2) but I like this one a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
 {
      return string.Join("~", first).Contains(string.Join("~", second));
 }
```

A little bit less "klugy", at least avoid some work for long long lists.

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
   {
       //trying to avoid multiple enumeration
        var firstList = first.ToList();
        var secondList = second.ToList();

        if (!secondList.Any(firstList.Contains)) return false;
        if (secondList.Count() > firstList.Count()) return false;
        if (Math.Max(firstList.Count(), secondList.Count()) > 99999)
             throw new ShouldNotUseThisUglyMethodException("I'm too kludgy to be used. Let me die...");
        return string.Join("~", firstList).Contains(string.Join("~", secondList));
    }
```

Comment: If you want less kludgy than this, use `.ToArray()` on your lists then use a similar algorithm as String.Contains() ;)

Answer (score 0):

This version uses a queue to store the possible subsequences.  It only iterates through `haystack` once aside from the initial `Take()`, and it stops iterating once it finds a match.  However, it mutates variables in a LINQ statement.

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle)
{
    var needleList = needle.ToList();
    var queue = new Queue<T>(haystack.Take(needleList.Count - 1));
    return haystack.Skip(needleList.Count - 1)
                   .Any( hay =>   
                       {
                           queue.Enqueue(hay);
                           bool areEqual = queue.SequenceEqual(needleList);
                           queue.Dequeue();
                           return areEqual;
                       });  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the work of hashes. Note there are some checks which could be done to immediately return a false, but I only show the meat of the process. Here it is in handy extension format:

*Updated to Handle Order*

```
void Main()
{
    var first        = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 5 };
    var firstInOrder = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    var second       = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var third        = new List<int>() { 1, 10, 20 };

    Console.WriteLine( first.FoundInOther( second ) );        // False
    Console.WriteLine( firstInOrder.FoundInOther( second ) ); // True
    Console.WriteLine( first.FoundInOther( third ) );         // False

}

public static class NumberExtensions
{

    public static bool FoundInOther( this IEnumerable<int> initial, IEnumerable<int> other )
    {
        int index = -1;
        var asDictionary = other.ToDictionary( itm => itm, itm => ++index );

        index = -1;
        return initial.All( oth => asDictionary.ContainsKey( oth ) && (asDictionary[oth] == ++index));
    }

}
```

Comment: Try with `var fourth = new List<int>() { 5, 2 };` Your method returns `true`, when I'd like it to return `false` (the order is important).

Comment: @hehewaffles Done see example. Simply put in the index into container of the KVP.

Comment: It still only tests the beginning of the sequence.  For example, `{2, 3}` should be found in `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.