# Find list in another list

Tags: c#, list, sublist

Is there an easy way to find one list in another, taking the order into consideration too? (Besides looping through them.) Basically like the way String's `.IndexOf` works.

```
string[] lookInThis = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
string[] lookForThis1 = { "b", "c" };
string[] lookForThis2 = { "b", "d" };

int FoundLoc = string.Join(",", lookInThis).IndexOf(string.Join(",", lookForThis1));
```

This works for my strings, but feels like it can be improved.

In my example, these are my expected outputs:

```
lookForThis1   1
lookForThis2  -1 or something like that.
```

Comment: for `lookForThis1` would the index be 1 instead, the index of the start of the found sequence?

Comment: Oh, yes, I'll update. Yes, I need the index of the beginning of the matching sequence.

Comment: Your current method returns twice as high as it should be. Also worth noting it won't work properly at all for `lookInThis = { "a","b,c","c", "d","d" };`. The first problem can be fixed by dividing by two(provided all strings in `lookInThis` are only length 1, the second requires rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: I don't think there such functionality exists. Usually lists, or in your case string arrays, are meant to have more than one character so the search would not be as simple.

Comment: Here is a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list

Comment: That is true, but I have unique items in the list, so `"b,c"` can never happen. My list can only contain `"a","b","c" and "-"`.

Comment: @Pol thanks, I didn't find that thread!

Comment: sometimes you just have to type the looping code. I am sure some Linq wizard will post a nice one-liner but it wont be obvious to a reader of the code later. And the compiler will still end up doing the same looping you would have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're asking. Not exactly pretty as I just threw it together and I'm no LINQ genie:

```
    public int SublistIndex(string[] lookInThis, string[]lookForThis)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < lookInThis.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (lookInThis.ElementAt(i).Equals(lookForThis.First()))
            {
                //Found the first element of the list we are searching for
                int j;

                //Now we need to check if the other elements are there in correct order
                for (j = 0; j < lookForThis.Count(); j++)
                {
                    if (i + j == lookInThis.Count())
                    {
                        //Reached the end of the lookInThis list with no match
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if (!lookInThis.ElementAt(i + j).Equals(lookForThis.ElementAt(j)))
                    {
                        //Sequence is not identical, stop inner loop
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (j == lookForThis.Count())
                {
                    //found it!
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        //reached the end and didn't find it
        return -1;
    }
```

Tested with this:

```
        string[] t1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
        string[] t2 = { "b", "c" };
        string[] t3 = { "b", "d" };
        int tt1 = SublistIndex(t1, t2);
        int tt2 = SublistIndex(t1, t3);
```

`tt1 = 1` and `tt2=-1`

You can substitute `string` for any type basically, provided you also change the `.equals()` comparison to an appropriate one.

**How it works:**

It loops through `lookInThis` and when finding the starting element of `lookForThis` it starts another loop to compare them. If  it finds any elements don't match it breaks this loop an resumes. If it reaches the end of `lookForThis` it returns the index of the first loop. It returns -1 when it reaches the end of `lookInThis`. Quick and dirty, so probably not advised for huge lists.