# C# extract data from png file and append into another png file

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I'm develop app that extract data from first png image and append it into another png image.

It is game from illusion. they store data like character data into png image after IEND®B`. so it can change image of character by append character data at the end of new png file.

I have done it in python like this

```
with open (src_image_path, 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
    text = b"IEND\xaeB`\x82"
    data_to_write = s.split(text)
    with open (dest_image_path, 'ab') as newImage:
        for i in range(1,len(data_to_write)):
            newImage.write(data_to_write[i])
            newImage.write(text)
```

Note: first index is png image data of first image. I don't need it. because I want only data that come after first index to append into second image.

In C#

I try read all bytes into bytes array but can't find index of IEND®B`. it always return -1

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
byte[] byteToFind = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IEND®B`");
GetFirstOccurance(byteToFind ,bytes);

public static int GetFirstOccurance(byte[] byteToFind, byte[] byteArray)
{
    return Array.IndexOf(byteArray, byteToFind);
}
```

Note: I can find IEND®B` by open png file in notepad++. It always at the end of png file

how do I do it in C#

I want to copy data after IEND®B` in first png and append into second png.

Comment: You have written a function GetFirstOccurance, that returns something. Then you call that function without using the returned value. This hint should get you going further.

Answer (score 0):

The version of IndexOf you are using is probably this one:

[`public static int IndexOf (Array array, object? value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_)

I.e. search thru an un-typed array after a reference to an array.

I expect you would want to search after a specific sequence of bytes, but that is not what IndexOf does. You will probably need to write your own search-loop, or take a look at this question: [How to find index of sublist in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529727/how-to-find-index-of-sublist-in-list).